# Remove https from a certain page

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, https

My whole site is secure but I want to remove the https from a certain page. Is there a way to do that in the htaccess file or php code?

Here is my current htacces file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Added

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page [NC]
```

Works for desktops browsers. I tried opening the page on mobile safari on iphone 7 but the page comes back secure.

Cleared the cache and added this but still no luck

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude a certen page from https redirection using the following condition :

Put this right above the RewriteRule line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page [NC]
```

This skips the RewriteRule if requested uri matches the pattern and is **/page** .

Comment: Never mind its working now. I think it takes a while to take effect.

Comment: Just tested it on a phone and now it tells me the page is secure again. How do you disable it on a phone?

Comment: it could be due your phone browser cache. Clear browser caches.

Comment: I cleared the data on safari for iphone and added meta tags <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

And still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a regexp expert but probably something like that?

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*target)(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(target)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

With `target` being your endpoint.